# GeoServer becomes overwhelmed

Tags: geoserver, ecw

I have using GeoServer 2.22 with default setting and configuration values. I uploaded approximately 100GB of data as ECW files.
When I run the server and display the maps by Arcgis Runtime SDK, it works well at first but after 2-3 min later, it makes my computer slow down and overwhelmed.

What can be the issue?
Is it because 100GB of ECW file is a lot for GeoServer to handle?

P.S:
number of cores in my pc is 10 and ram is 15GB

Comment: did you follow the suggestions in https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/index.html#production?

Comment: When it's overwhelmed, if the admin UI is still working, go to "Server status", "JVM console" tab, click on "thread dump" and share the results here. By the way, last time I checked using ECW in a server-side application required buying a dedicated license from Hexagon (while it was free to use on desktops instead). Not sure if things changed in the meantime, all people I talked to eventually switched away from ECW for this task.

Comment: You are misunderstanding, you get the software but it's not legal to use unless you get the license agreement. Anyways, I might be wrong, but I'd confirm it before Hexagon comes knocking at your door.

Comment: Ok thanks for warning. I will check that

Comment: in the official doc of geoserver, it says: "If you have ECW files you have several non-ideal options. If you are only using GeoServer for educational or non-profit purposes you can use the plugin for free. If not you need to buy a license, since it’s server software. " here is the link to the page: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/data.html